# Ci vuole un bel fegato!

Tags: word-usage, phrase-origin

*Avere un bel fegato* o *ci vuole un bel fegato* sono espressioni molto comuni usate per esprimere il concetto che ci vuole un bel coraggio o bisogna essere sfrontati per poter fare qualcosa di riprovevole.

- Ci vuole un bel fegato a derubare la povera gente.
- Bisogna avere fegato per viaggiare in treno senza biglietto.

[Avere un bel fegato](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/F/fegato.shtml) :

> Essere impudenti, sfrontati; commettere azioni spudorate o riprovevoli senza porsi problemi.

Perché *il fegato* viene usato come metafora di *coraggio o impudenza*? Ci sono ragioni storiche o letterarie che hanno dato origine a questi modi di dire?

Comment: in certi dialetti siciliani si usa dire (anche) soltanto "Ci vuole fegato..!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il legame tra fegato e coraggio è antichissimo. In latino lo [*iecur*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Djecur), il fegato, era la sede dell’anima e degli affetti. Allo stesso modo, in greco lo [*ἧπαρ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dh%28%3Dpar) (hḗpar) era la sede delle passioni.

L’accezione è passata anche in italiano ed è rimasta come relitto di concezioni mediche arcaiche, nell’espressione idiomatica in esame e in altre.

Il *Tommaseo-Bellini*, alla voce «[fegato](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items/47179)», dice:

> **Aver fegato**; Coraggio ardimentoso, ma in cose materiali. *Uomo che ha fegato*. Il modo vien forse dall'avere gli antichi posta nel fegato
>   la sede degli appetiti.

«Coraggio […] in cose materiali», coerentemente con la concezione greca, esposta per esempio nel *Fedro* di Platone, del dualismo tra ragione e passione, intesa come concupiscenza, appetito materiale, ecc.

Answer (score 5):

Questa espressione sembrerebbe derivare dalla [teoria umorale](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_umorale) di Ippocrate, secondo cui la bile gialla, presente nel fegato, è associata al fuoco, quindi alla collera e all'avventatezza.